# Angular Routing RootPath With Parameters

Tags: angular, angular4-forms, angular4-router

We're developing an admin panel with using angular 4.
And we have a routing file for one of our modules like in below:

```
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { ShowPeriodsComponent } from './periods/show-periods/show-periods.component';
import { CreatePeriodsComponent } from './periods/create-periods/create-periods.component';
import { EditPeriodsComponent } from './periods/edit-periods/edit-periods.component';
import { ShowVideosComponent} from './videos/show-videos/show-videos.component';
import { CreateVideosComponent} from './videos/create-videos/create-videos.component';
import { EditVideosComponent} from './videos/edit-videos/edit-videos.component';
import { PeriodCommonComponent } from './periodCommon.component';


export const EvolutionsRoutes: Routes = [{
  path: '',
  component: PeriodCommonComponent,
  children: [
    {
      path: 'periods',
      children: [
        { path: '', component: ShowPeriodsComponent, data: { heading: 'Assesment Periods' } },
        { path: 'create', component: CreatePeriodsComponent, data: { heading: 'Create assesment period' } },
        { path: 'edit/:id', component: EditPeriodsComponent, data: { heading: 'Edit assesment period' } },
      ]
    } ,
    {
      path: 'videos',
      children: [
        { path: ':id', component: ShowVideosComponent, data: { heading: 'Assesment Videos' } },
        { path: 'create', component: CreateVideosComponent, data: { heading: 'Create assesment videos' } },
        { path: 'edit/:id', component: EditVideosComponent, data: { heading: 'Edit assesment videos' } },
      ]
    }
  ]

}];
```

However  the problem starts here. Our root path is:  **/evolutions**
, and everything works ok when I call below urls:

```
/evolutions/periods
/evolutions/periods/edit/{periodId}
/evolutions/videos/{periodId}
/evolutions/videos/edit/{videoId}
```

But when I call the below link

**/evolutions/videos/create**

The page fails to load. And the reason is: it calls one of the methods in the constructor of
/evolutions/videos  link(I mean in ShowVideosComponent)
However I dont want that link to be loaded all I want is to load the template file related with /evolutions/videos/create link.
Is something like that possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't it just a path order problem ?

When you type an URL, your router checks every path in your router configuration one by one from top to bottom.

Your router considers that /evolutions/videos/create is a valid path for your ShowVideosComponent where :id = 'create'.

If you put your videos/:id path below your videos/create path, it should work.